# NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#new in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I messed something up, and I dont know where. When I run my rails server, it gives me : *NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#new* , and : *undefined method `configure_permitted_parameters' for #*
The error message says the code error is :

```
        case filter
    when Symbol
      lambda { |target, _, &blk| target.send filter, &blk }
    when String
      l = eval "lambda { |value| #{filter} }"
      lambda { |target, value| target.instance_exec(value, &l) }
```

starting on line 430, error on 432 (line 3 in this). I cant find the file this is in.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific ? Rails version ? Devise version ? Full stack trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on rails 4 ?

Try adding

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  # Replace the keys to fit your needs
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
end
```

To your application_controller.rb

Please also read the following:

This will help you https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters